# Proving every metric space is normal

Tags: general-topology, continuity, metric-spaces

> Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space with disjoint, non-empty, closed subsets $A$ and $B$.
> Define
> \begin{equation*}
> f \colon X \to \mathbb{R},
> \quad
> x \mapsto \frac{d(x,A)}{d(x,A) + d(x,B)} \,.
> \end{equation*}
> Show that $f$ is continuous and conclude that every metric space is normal.

I've been using the $\varepsilon$-$\delta$-method to prove continuity but I cant get anywhere meaningful.

Comment: It is possible, but you safe yourself from some writing if instead use some properties of continuous functions. Try proving that it is a quotient of continuous function in which the denominator is never zero. That each $x\mapsto d(x,A)$ and $x\mapsto d(x,B)$ is continuous you can do from the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition. Keep in mind the triangle inequality. That the denominator is not zero follows from $A$ and $B$ being disjoint.

Comment: @logarithm It's worth mentioning that the denominator is non-vanishing does *not* follow from $A$ and $B$ being disjoint; one needs to use more of the assumptions here.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please [do not use image for the critical part](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20529/356647) of the question. Please edit and use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020) to properly format math expressions.

Comment: Wow!  Cant believe I didnt think of that. Thanks! The denominator is nonzero because x cannot be in both A and B so at least one of d(x,A) d(x,B) must be greater than zero.  So I think logarithm was right.

Answer (score 2):

Let $f_A(x)=d(x,A)=\inf_{a\in A}d(x,a)$. Then $f_A$ is continuous (indeed, Lipschitz continuous). For if $x,y\in X$, $a\in A$ then $d(x,a)\leqslant d(x,y)+d(y,a)$ and hence by taking the infimum of $a\in A$, $$d(x,A)\leqslant d(x,y)+d(y,a).$$ From this we have $d(y,a)\geqslant d(x,A)-d(x,y)$, so taking the infimum of $a\in A$ yields $d(y,A)\geqslant d(x,A)-d(x,y) $, or $$d(x,A)-d(y,A)\leqslant d(x,y).$$ Interchanging $x$ and $y$, we have $d(y,A)-d(x,A)\leqslant d(y,x)$, so that $$|d(x,A)-d(y,A)|\leqslant d(x,y). $$

Let $f_B(x)=d(x,B)$. Then $f_B$ is also continuous, and so too is the sum $f_A+f_B$. Since $A$ and $B$ are disjoint and closed, a point $x\in X$ can be in at most one of the closures of $A$ and $B$. Therefore $f_A(x)+f_B(x)>0$, from which we see that the quotient $f = f_A/(f_A+f_B)$ is continuous.