# How to use Lemma of Urysohn ??

Tags: general-topology

Let U, V be two non-empty, closed, disjoint subsets of a metric space X. How can I prove that there is a
continuous function $f : X → [0, 1] $ with $f|_U = 1 $and $f|_V = 0.$??I am not sure how to use  Urysohn's lemma in this. Or at least any hints, explanations, how to begin would be wonderful!

Comment: Why are you unsure about using Urysohn’s lemma? This is almost exactly the conclusion of the Urysohn lemma

Comment: To be fair never used it so that is why I'm not sure how to do this

Comment: This answers your question: [Proving every metric space is normal](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3208752/proving-every-metric-space-is-normal). [Urysohn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urysohn%27s_lemma) is overkill for metric spaces.

Comment: To elaborate, Urysohn is overkill for metric spaces because you’re already given a real valued function you can manipulate - the metric itself! To say anymore would be to give the game away. You should add your thoughts anyhow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let U, V be two non-empty, closed, disjoint subsets of a metric space $(X,d)$. You can show that all metric spaces are normal spaces. Define
\begin{equation*}
f: X \to \mathbb{R}, \
x \mapsto \frac{d(x,U)}{d(x,U) + d(x,V)}.
\end{equation*}
where $d(x,U)=$$inf${$d(x,u),u\in U$} and $d(x,U)=0\iff x\in U$,

$d(x,V)=$$inf${$d(x,v),v\in V$} and $d(x,V)=0\iff x\in V$

It is easy to prove that $f$ is continuous and conclude that every metric space is normal. Now Uryshon states that a topological space
X is normal if and only if, for any U,V two non-empty closed disjoint subsets
$\exists f:X\to[0,1]$ with$f(U)=0,f(V)=1$. And that is what you want to show. $\square$